# What do they mean when they say LINQ is composable?

Tags: linq

What does it mean and why (if at all) is it important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can add additional "operators" to a query.  It's important because you can do it extremely efficiently.

For example, let's say you have a method that returns a list (enumerable) of employees:

```
var employees = GetEmployees();
```

and another method that uses that one to return all managers:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> GetManagers()
{
    return GetEmployees().Where(e => e.IsManager);
}
```

You can call that function to get managers that are approaching retirement and send them an email like this:

```
foreach (var manager in GetManagers().Where(m => m.Age >= 65) )
{
   SendPreRetirementMessage(manager);
}
```

Pop quiz: How many times will that iterate over your employees list?  The answer is *exactly* once; the entire operation is still just O(n)!

Also, I don't need to have separate methods for this. I could compose a query with these steps all in one place:

```
var retiringManagers = GetEmployees();
retiringManagers = retiringManagers.Where(e => e.IsManager);
retiringManagers = retiringManagers.Where(m => m.Age >= 65);
foreach (var manager in retiringMangers)
{
    SendPreRetirementMessage();
}
```

One cool thing about this is that I can change is at run time, such that I can include or not include one part of the composition inside an `if` block, such that the decision to use a specific filter is made at run time, and everything still comes out nice and pretty.

Comment: The exactly once part is the payoff of the composability then, eh?

Comment: Part of it.  The rest is that you can take a method like "GetEmployees()" or "GetManagers()" and use it in an efficient way as a building block to build (compose) new, more complicated queries.  Without linq, you'd have to start from scratch with your employees list for each method.

Answer (score 4):

I think it means that you can daisy chain your queries, like this

```
var peterJacksonsTotalBoxOffice
    = movies.Where(movie => movie.Director == "Peter Jackson")
        .Sum(movie => movie.BoxOffice);
```