# Group By in Entity Framework based on condition

Tags: linq, group-by

I have a group by clause where I am selecting key, however my problem is my key is changing based on some condition, is there any chance I can set key in one line?

```
if (IsDefaultFund) 
{
 _summaries = (from sa in SourceDataset.SourceInvestorAllocations
join ea in EfrontNavDataset.EfrontNavInvestorAllocations on
new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, 
Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
equals new { SourceDatasetId = ea.EfrontNavDataset.SourceDatasetId, Iqid = ea.IqId, ShareIndex = ea.ShareIndex } 
join pn in PriorNavPositions on new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, 
Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
equals new { SourceDatasetId = pn.SourceDatasetId, 
Iqid = pn.SubscriberFiid, ShareIndex = pn.ShareIndex } into pnj 
from pn in pnj.DefaultIfEmpty(new EfrontPriorNavPosition()) 
group new { sa, ea, pn } by new { ea.ShareIndex, sa.ClassName } into g 
}
else 
{
_summaries = (from sa in SourceDataset.SourceInvestorAllocations
join ea in EfrontNavDataset.EfrontNavInvestorAllocations on
new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, 
Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
equals new { SourceDatasetId = ea.EfrontNavDataset.SourceDatasetId, Iqid = ea.IqId, ShareIndex = ea.ShareIndex } 
join pn in PriorNavPositions on new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, 
Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
equals new { SourceDatasetId = pn.SourceDatasetId, 
Iqid = pn.SubscriberFiid, ShareIndex = pn.ShareIndex } into pnj 
from pn in pnj.DefaultIfEmpty(new EfrontPriorNavPosition()) 
group new { sa, ea, pn } by new { ea.ShareIndex, sa.Straegy} into g 
}
```

Everything is identical in both queries apart from below line, where I am creating new group by **sa.Strartegy**

```
If(IsDefaultFund)
   group new { sa, ea, pn } by new {ea.ShareIndex, sa.ClassName } 
else
   group new { sa, ea, pn } by new { ea.ShareIndex, sa.Strategy }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can create an `IQueryable` variable that contains the query before the grouping and only add the grouping conditionally.

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold, Can you give me sample plz as i tried but its not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you tried; "its not working" doesn't say much. Also, while you're at it, please revise the queries to make it more clear which parts are identical.

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold, I have edit my queries to make it more clearer

Answer (score 0):

Since LINQ queries are [composable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1145746/861716) you can build the major part of the query first and then only add the grouping conditionally:

```cs
var firstPart = (from sa in SourceDataset.SourceInvestorAllocations
    join ea in EfrontNavDataset.EfrontNavInvestorAllocations on
    new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, 
        Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
    equals new { SourceDatasetId = ea.EfrontNavDataset.SourceDatasetId, 
        Iqid = ea.IqId, ShareIndex = ea.ShareIndex } 
    join pn in PriorNavPositions on new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, 
        Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } 
    equals new { SourceDatasetId = pn.SourceDatasetId, 
        Iqid = pn.SubscriberFiid, ShareIndex = pn.ShareIndex } into pnj 
    from pn in pnj.DefaultIfEmpty(new EfrontPriorNavPosition()) 
    select new { sa, ea, pn };
var grouped = IsDefaultFund
    ? firstPart.GroupBy(x => new { x.ea.ShareIndex, Name = x.sa.ClassName })
    : firstPart.GroupBy(x => new { x.ea.ShareIndex, Name = x.sa.Strategy });
```

Note that (because of `Name =`) the grouping keys have the same property names so both groupings have the same type (assuming that both `ClassName` and `Strategy` are strings). I don't know the type of `_summaries`, I assume your code also contains an operation to convert the grouping into `_summaries`.

Comment: Thanks Gert Arnold, worked like a charm